# Fortran implied do write speedup

Tags: performance, io, fortran

**tl;dr**:  I found that an "implied do" write was slower than an explicit one under certain circumstances, and want to understand why/if I can improve this.

**Details**:
I've got a code that does something to the effect of:

```
DO i=1,n
  calculations...

  !m, x, and y all change each pass through the loop
  IF(m.GT.1)THEN   
    DO j=1,m
      WRITE(10,*)x(j),y(j)  !where 10 is an output file
    ENDDO
  ENDIF
ENDDO
```

The output file ends up being fairly large, and so it seems like the writing is a big performance factor, so I wanted to optimize it.  Before anyone asks, no, moving away from ASCII isn't an option due to various downstream requirements.  Accordingly, I rewrote the `IF` statement (and contents) as:

```
IF(m.GT.1)THEN
  !build format statement for write
  WRITE(mm1,*)m-1
  mm1=ADJUSTL(mm1)
  !implied do write statement
  WRITE(10,'('//TRIM(mm1)//'(i9,1x,f7.5/),i9,1x,f7.5)')(x(j),y(j),j=1,m)
ELSEIF(m.EQ.1)THEN
  WRITE(10,'(i9,1x,f7.5)')x(1),y(1)
ENDIF
```

This builds the format statement according to the # of values to be written out, then does a single write statement to output things.  I've found that the code actually runs slower with this formulation.  For reference, I've seen significant speedup on the same system (hardware and software) when going to an implied do write statement when the amount of data to be written was fixed.  Under the assumption that the `WRITE` statement, itself, is faster, then that would mean the overhead from the couple of lines building that statement are what take the added time, but that seems hard to believe.  For reference, `m` can vary a fair amount, but probably averages at least 1000.  Is the concatenation of strings `//` a very slow operator, or is there something else I'm missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you just use `write(10,'(i9,f8.5)') (...)` and rely on format reversion?

Comment: Ore use the `*` as multiplier, or just any large number like 999999.

Comment: The actual output format has a few more values, such that a `*` might lead to unwanted line wrapping.  But, I had no idea that either francescalus's approach of not specifying or VladimirF's of just using a number that's always larger than `m` were valid options.  I'll try them out and update.

Comment: @TTT, I believe Vladimir F's use of `*` was as an unlimited repeat count specifier (see F2008) rather than list-directed output.  So, you would have `write(10,'(*(i9,1x,f7,5,:,/))')` (with my suggested colon).

Comment: @francescalus Ah, I misunderstood, though I was also oblivious to that option.  Is there any difference between that and the idea you'd supplied `write(10,'(i9,f8.5)') (...)`?  Perhaps if an `ADVANCE='NO'` had been specified?

Comment: Before even jumping to search for the solution! can you quantify what you mean by slower? Give some actual numbers

Comment: @innoSPG Maybe 10-20% slower, vs. 50-1000% faster under other instances that I've done a comparison between the two.

Comment: @francescalus I tested your example, and it worked.  I didn't test Vladimir F's because I didn't want to have 2 instances going at the same time, as they could compete for disk resources.  If you'd care to turn the comment into an answer, I'll mark it as complete, otherwise I can do it.  Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't specific timing information to add, but your data transfer with an implied do loop is needlessly complicated.

In the first fragment, with the explicit looping, you are writing each pair of numbers to distinct records and you wish to repeat this output with the implied do loop.  To do this, you use the slash edit descriptor to terminate each record once a pair has been written.

The needless complexity comes from two areas:

- you have distinct cases for one/more than one pair;
- for the more-than-one case you construct a format including a "dynamic" repeat count.

As [Vladimir F comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302196/fortran-implied-do-write-speedup?noredirect=1#comment58315645_35302196) you could just use a very large repeat count: it isn't erroneous for an edit descriptor to be processed when there are no more items to be written.  The output terminates (successfully) when reaching such a non-matching descriptor.  You could, then, just write

```
 WRITE(10,'(*(i9,1x,f7.5/))') (x(j),y(j),j=1,m)  ! * replacing a large count
```

rather than the if construct and the format creation.

Now, this doesn't quite match your first output.  As I mentioned above, output termination comes about when a data edit descriptor is reached when there is no corresponding item to output.  This means that `/` will be processed before that happens: you have a final empty record.

The colon edit descriptor is useful here:

```
 WRITE(10,'(*(i9,1x,f7.5,:,/))') (x(j),y(j),j=1,m)
```

On reaching a `:` processing stops immediately if there is no remaining output item to process.

But my preferred approach is the far simpler

```
 WRITE(10,'(i9,1x,f7.5)') (x(j),y(j),j=1,m) ! No repeat count
```

You had the more detailed format to include record termination.  However, we have what is known as format reversion: if a format end is reached and more remains to be output then the record is terminated and processing goes back to the start of the format.

Whether these things make your output faster remains to be seen, but they certainly make the code itself much cleaner and clearer.

As a final note, it used to be trendy to avoid additional `X` editing.  If your numbers fit inside the field of width 7 then `1x,f7.5` could be replaced by `f8.5` and have the same look: the representation is right-justified in the field.  It was claimed that this reduction had performance benefits with fewer switching of descriptors.

Comment: I think you have a typo.  When I do `WRITE(10,'(i9,1x,f7.5/)')`, it add an extra blank line between each line of output, including the last one.  But without the slash, `WRITE(10,'(i9,1x,f7.5)')`, it works just fine.

Comment: Details on speedup:  The file is 114 GB, I'm running on a fairly efficient NAS geared towards large files.  Your recommended method `WRITE(10,'(i9,1x,f7.5)') (x(j),y(j),j=1,m)` shaved 52 minutes off of the overall run time.  I didn't try to determine how much of the run time was devoted just to outputting the file, but based on what I know about the code's performance, this equates to at least a 100% speedup for that part of the code, possibly up to ~500%.